# German locale & English CP language resulting in disappeared entries

Tags: control-panel, localization, language

I have just one locale (German, de). Now, I've changed my CP language to English ('defaultCpLanguage' => 'en' in general.php).

But now, all my entries have disappeared in the CP (Craft Pro 2.4.2670).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!
MISc

Comment: I've tried to change the preferredLocale directly in the database (table: craft_users) from NULL to 'de'. As a result I got the entries in the CP back, but also the German language ('defaultCpLanguage' => 'en' was ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#defaultCpLanguage):

> The default language that the Control Panel should be rendered in, for users that haven’t specified their Preferred Locale.

`defaultCpLanguage` is only applied for users that don't have a Preferred Locale set in their user profile.

Your entries disappeared because you don't have any entries created in the English locale, yet.  You might need to enable `en` under the Section's settings before that's an option.

Comment: So, it is not possible to have an English CP with a foreign language locaöe only? To have this would be nice, because it is difficult to follow the English documentation with a translation based CP (unfortunately the German CP translation quality is not so good).

Comment: Why not have both `en` and `de` locales in Settings->Locales, then you can view the CP in English, but enter content in German?

Comment: Alternatively if you want to help improve the German CP translations, I can send you an invite, too. ;)

Comment: Will do!  Shoot an email over to support@buildwithcraft.com, so I'll know where to send it.

Comment: I have the same issue, also my globals are disappearing when deleting the 'en' locale, from what i read it is not possible to have 'en' CP and different locale for entries :( but why are globals disappearing is this a bug?