# Output postDate in a different language than CP

Tags: localization, control-panel, language, postdate

How to retrieve the postDate of an entry in a different language than the CP.
In the general config settings i have the following,

```
    'defaultCpLanguage' => 'en'
```

But i would like to display the dates in the frontend in a different language. As in translated month names. Is this possible?

I tried the following with no result:

```
    {{ entry.postDate | date("d/F/y", "Europe/Paris") }}
    {{entry.postDate.format("d F y")}} #}
    <span class="date">{{entry.postDate | date('d F Y')}}</span>
```

The format works, but there is no translation.

Comment: I came across this post: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/is-it-possible-to-output-month-names-in-my-native-language is there a better solution around? or is this the only way? So to summarize you should install craft in your native language and after that set the CP to English?

Comment: I changed the locale in the database as explained in the question above but now my CP is in the same language as the db i thought defaultCpLanguage would override this...this makes no sense

Comment: I don't think I'm following 100%. The language the CP is being displayed in and the locale that is being displayed on the front-end are two separate things. Can you clarify more what you're trying to do?

Comment: That second parameter you set to "Europe/Paris" in the `date` filter is to set the timezone, NOT the language!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need Craft Pro and even then it's not possible
to have the CP in a language that is not installed as a front-end locale.

The (new) `defaultCpLanguage` setting doesn't change this. See Brad's
answers here:
[Change system language](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5001/125) +
[German locale & English CP language resulting in disappeared entries](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10576/125)

But to help you with your date problem. It is possible to access most data from
[craft/app/framework/i18n/data/](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/tree/master/app/framework/i18n/data) via `craft.i18n` methods.

```
{% macro dateFormat(date, locale) %}
    {% set localeData = craft.i18n.getLocaleData(locale|default('de')) %}
    {{
        localeData.getWeekdayName(date|date('w')) ~ ', ' ~
        date|date('j ') ~
        localeData.getMonthName(date|date('m')) ~
        date|date(' Y')
    }}
{% endmacro %}
{% import _self as macros %}

{% for locale in ['en', 'es', 'fr', 'de', 'ru', 'nl', 'no'] %}
    <li>{{ macros.dateFormat(now, locale) }}</li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your looking to just replace month or day names you could do something like this:

```
{% set translations = {
    'January': 'janvier', 
    'February': 'février', 
    'March':'mars', 
    'April':'avril'} 
 %}    

{{ entry.postDate|date('d F Y')|replace(translations) }}
```

You could add any amount of translations in that object.